# How to get specific keys in Array of Hashes?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of Hashes:

```
[{"folder"=>"j"}, {"path"=>"p"}, {"folder"=>"b"}]
```

I merge them via:

```
flat_map(&:entries)
  .group_by(&:first)
  .map{|k,v| Hash[k, v.map(&:last)]}
```

Then I get:

```
[{"folder"=>["j", "b"]}, {"path"=>["p"]}]
```

as expected.

My question is, `:folder` and `:path` (I will also have more keys) can be randomly ordered. Instead of looping and checking for key names, Is it possible to get each hash separately? For example;

```
# After merging...
folders = elem[:folder] # => ["j", "b"]
paths =  elem[:path].. # => ["p"]
```

Basically I would like to get `:folder` and `:path` without looping all the time.

Comment: What is `elem`? Where dies `:folder` and `:path` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different approach in the first place:

```
collection = [{"folder"=>"j"}, {"path"=>"p"}, {"folder"=>"b"}]
```

Using `each_with_object` (or a similar approach with `reduce`):

```
collection.each_with_object({}) do |values, s|
  values.each do |key, value|
    (s[key.to_sym] ||= []) << value
  end
end
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/repls/LuckySvelteAlabamamapturtle)

or `group_by` and `transform_values`:

```
collection.
  group_by { |item| item.first.first.to_sym  }.
  transform_values { |values| values.flat_map(&:values) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem by this:

```
elem = [{"folder"=>["j", "b"]}, {"path"=>["p"]}]
merged = elem.reduce({}, :merge)
# => {"folder" => ["j", "b"], "path" => ["p"]}
merged["folder"]
# => ["j", "b"]
merged["path"]
# => ["p"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ar =[{"folder"=>"j"}, {"path"=>"p"}, {"folder"=>"b"}]
elem = Hash.new{[]}

ar.each{|hash| hash.each{|k,v| elem[k] <<= v }}
folders, paths = elem.values_at("folder", "path")
```